# Ignoring a method call inside a base class method

Tags: c#, oop

How can I ignore a method call inside a base class method when overriding it? Like in the example below execute all the 100 lines of code and ignore calling the method `insideMethod1()` in the derived classes. is there a way to do it without repeating the code

```
public class A
virtual method1(){
 // 100 lines of code
 insideMethod1();
}
public class B : A
override method1(){
// call the 100 lines of code but ignore calling insideMethod1()
}
```

Comment: You should refactor your code so that you don't need to do that.

Comment: are these the same 100 lines of code in the overridden method1 as in the base class?

Answer (score 4):

You can do it contrariwise - override `insideMethod1` so that it will not do anything:

```
public class A
{
    public void method1() {
       // 100 lines of code
       insideMethod1();
    }

    protected virtual void insideMethod1() { /* some work here */ }
}

public class B : A
{
    protected override void insideMethod1() { }
}
```

Further reading: [Template Method Pattern](http://www.dofactory.com/net/template-method-design-pattern)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not so familiar with c#, but I would think you could pass a bool argument to the function which determines whether you call the nested function.

```
public class A
virtual method1(bool callInsideMethod = true){
 // 100 lines of code
 if(callInsideMethod)
     insideMethod1();
}

public class B : A
override method1(bool callInsideMethod = false){
// call the 100 lines of code but ignore calling insideMethod1()
}
```